# How to deal with a method in a SOAP-Call and its parameters

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, saaj

the API says I have to use the method "getStock" and following parameters:
accessToken,company,itemNumber,commissionNumber.
I wrote this code but it doesn't work.

```
    SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
    //envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("sam", "http://samples.axis2.techdive.in");

    // SOAP Body
    SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
    SOAPElement method = soapBody.addChildElement("getStock");
    SOAPElement firstParam = method.addChildElement("accessToken");
    firstParam.addTextNode("xxx");

    SOAPElement secondParam = method.addChildElement("company");
    secondParam.addTextNode("AS");

    SOAPElement thirdParam = method.addChildElement("itemNumber");
    thirdParam.addTextNode("020001");

    SOAPElement fourthParam = method.addChildElement("commissionNumber");
    fourthParam.addTextNode("0");

    soapMessage.saveChanges();
```

And what about the NamespaceDeclaration?

I get this error:

Response SOAP Message = 
ns2:Client
Cannot find dispatch method for {}getStock
Process finished with exit code 0

Greetings Andrew

Comment: Is this a requirement that you don't use an easier method, for example the wsimport tool to import the target wsdl and created clients classes for your, which then will create the SOAP messages automatically?

Comment: I gave it a try but it leads to an error too. [ERROR] org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://login.as-creation.de/soap/stock?xsd=1; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 50; Leerstellen erforderlich zwischen publicId und systemId.
  Zeile 1 von https://login.as-creation.de/soap/stock?wsdl

        WSDL konnte nicht geparst werden

Comment: In that case I would try to solve that error first instead of working around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to specify the prefix and the name space, you can use a `Qname` object `(import javax.xml.namespace.QName;)` like this:

```
QName stockQname = new QName("http://your_namespace_uri.com",
                "getStock", "prefix");
```

Change the `prefix` to your actual prefix.

Change the namespace to your actual namespaceuri

I rewrote your code to use Qnames:

```
private static void test() throws SOAPException {

        MessageFactory factory = MessageFactory
                .newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_1_PROTOCOL);
        SOAPMessage message = factory.createMessage();
        SOAPPart soapPart = message.getSOAPPart();

        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();

        SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();

        QName stockQname = new QName("http://your_namespace_uri.com",
                "getStock", "prefix");
        SOAPBodyElement stockElement = soapBody.addBodyElement(stockQname);

        QName accessQname = new QName("accessToken");
        SOAPElement accessElement = stockElement.addChildElement(accessQname);
        accessElement.addTextNode("xxx");

        QName companyQname = new QName("company");
        SOAPElement companyElement = stockElement.addChildElement(companyQname);
        companyElement.addTextNode("AS");

        QName itemQname = new QName("itemNumber");
        SOAPElement itemElement = stockElement.addChildElement(itemQname);
        itemElement.addTextNode("020001");

        QName commisionQname = new QName("commissionNumber");
        SOAPElement commissionElement = stockElement
                .addChildElement(commisionQname);
        commissionElement.addTextNode("0");

        message.saveChanges();
}
```

And this is the generated SOAP message:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <prefix:getStock xmlns:prefix="http://your_namespace_uri.com">
      <accessToken>xxx</accessToken>
      <company>AS</company>
      <itemNumber>020001</itemNumber>
      <commissionNumber>0</commissionNumber>
    </prefix:getStock>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I am using this SAAJ library

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
    <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.25</version>
</dependency>
```

If you want to use SOAP 1.2 message protocol, simply change this line:

```
MessageFactory factory = MessageFactory
                .newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_1_PROTOCOL);
```

To this line:

```
MessageFactory factory = MessageFactory
                .newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL);
```

Hope this helps